# How can I get the current route in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing

I found several ways including

```
Route::getFacadeRoot()->current()->uri();
Route::getCurrentRoute()->getPath();
```

The problem is it's only giving my path pattern and not the actual compiled route that the user entered with the parameters.

It seems I can find a way to put it back together as the `Route::current()` also gives me the parameters as an array but is there a less manual way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the current url from the Request facade:

```
$fullUrl = Request::url();
```

If you want to get just the uri:

```
$uri = Request::path();
```

You can also check the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests) for more information of other useful methods.